# How to start adding REST calls in MEAN stack

Tags: mean-stack

I am using MEAN stack for my Node.js application.
Where i can start defining my routes ?

I read this tutorial https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial
But it is telling to install express separately after installing mean and creating separate package.json for node.js, doing everything in a separate folder. But if we do so then what is the use of mean here. 
As i think we supposed to hook up those calls here in Mean package not create separate folder and install node.js there separately.

Can anyone please help me to figure out, how can i start adding my REST API in MEAN stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Mean stack: Node.js code is inside the 'modules//server/' folder.
Its paths are already included. For adding new node.js module in MEAN stack we can create our module in 'modules' directory and start working.

For my work i want to add my REST API. I have created following files:

```
./modules/TC/server/controllers/TC.server.controller.js
./modules/TC/server/models/TC.server.model.js
./modules/TC/server/routes/TC.server.route.js
```

Answer (score 0):

It may help you to download the completed source code and look at how they've laid everything out for you.

A few points:

- mean is simply an acronym consisting of the different levels of the application stack... **M**ongoDB, **E**xpress, **A**ngular, and **N**ode... not something you install and use.
- the `package.json` file is kind of like the table of contents of your node backend. It's where you can store some metadata about your application, keep track of dependencies (and their required versions) for development and production, one of which will be Express.
- Express is a very popular module built on Node that makes handling HTTP requests very simple. It's what allows you to write:

  ```
  app.get('/', function(req, res) {
      /* do whatever you want to do when the user requests the root route,
         in this case send 200 status code and the message */
      res.status(200).send('Hi there!');
  });
  ```

You don't have to separate everything out into disparate files and folders -- you could put all of the backend functionality (routing, mongo db connection, mongoose schemas, etc.) in app.js, but it would be a monolith of code. So the *node way* is to separate the various concerns into their own files and `require` them as needed.

The thinkster tutorial helps you to build out a fairly robust functionality, but to get the basics of what's going on, you may want to start with a simpler tutorial, like [scotch.io's MEAN starter app](https://scotch.io/tutorials/setting-up-a-mean-stack-single-page-application) or the like.